# Delete time stamped files if the file is greater than 30 days

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a script where it would delete anything that is older than 30 days. All the files that it should look through which should be deleted after 30 days should be inside a folder called "whitelisted" and all the files inside whitelisted are txt files. The files are date stamped in milli seconds (example 1657043933694.txt). What I tried doing in the script below is trying to see if the date of the file + the time in months is greater or = to the date right now. And if it is it would remove the file which doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure how I can get this problem resolved by any help is appreciated. I am new to coding so you might have to explain how and where I should change. Thanks! (Oh yeah one more thing I have script above this which is for discord but I need this to run every 5 minutes or so, and there are more than 1 file which are all date stamped).

```
const testFolder = './whitelisted/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
  if (file + 2629800000 >= Date.now()) {
    const deleteFile = async (filePath) => {
        try {
          await fsPromises.unlink(filePath);
          console.log('Successfully removed file!');
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You never run the function you created
2. The condition should be reversed
3. file + 2629800000 will return a string, but should a number

```
const testFolder = './whitelisted/';
const fs = require('fs').promises; // fixed lib import

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
  // converted file to number, changed >= to <=
  if (+file + 2629800000 <= Date.now()) {
    const deleteFile = async (filePath) => {
        try {
          await fsPromises.unlink(filePath);
          console.log('Successfully removed file!');
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
    deleteFile(file) // runned function
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work :( @konrad Linkowski

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's answer is mostly correct, except for one key thing.  The `file` in the array of files will include the extension.  So you will need to slice off the extension before casting the file name as a Number and adding the milliseconds.

use the `split` method to split it on the extension value (".txt") before doing any calculations on it.

```
const testFolder = './whitelisted/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {

  // splitting on extension and getting first element in array
  let [fileTime] = file.split(".txt")

  // unary "+" in front to cast as Number type
  if (+fileTime + 2629800000 >= Date.now()) {
    const deleteFile = async (filePath) => {
        try {
          await fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
          console.log('Successfully removed file!');
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
    deleteFile(file)
  }
});
```

Comment: comes as fs.readdirSync is not a function :(

Comment: Try again, fixed the import

Comment: When I try to make it delete files older than 1 minute it doesnt work

Comment: Change the comparison to greater than or equal to `>=`

Comment: what do you mean, isn't that already done?

Comment: You tell me, what is in your code?

Comment: I don't understand. I copied the thing from there and tested it out in a new .js file. So right now it is only that script